# Find the week of month in Impala

Tags: sql, impala, hue

I want to print in impala that 2020-03-01 is in the first week of March.
How is this possible in Impala? I managed only to find the weekofyear().

Comment: Something similar to: `weekofyear(column) - weekofyear(YEAR(column) + MONTH(column) + '1') + 1`.

Comment: @jarlh Thanks for your answer. Although this appeared: Arithmetic operation requires numeric operands. I am not sure if impala can understand the +'1'

Comment: See it as pseudo-code. I have no idea how to "build" the January first date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "week of month" you mean that the first week is days 1-7, the second 8-14, and so on, then you can use:

```
select ceiling( day(ingestion_date) / 7.0 ) as week_of_month
```

Comment: Yes exactly, is the same I think with my answer above.

Comment: @DrGenius . . . This should produce the same results.  However, it does not require converting the date to a string, it does not use implicit conversion to an int, and it uses only arithmetic and proper `date` functions.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out,

```
ceil(cast(substr(ingestion_date,7,2) as int)/7) as wmonth
```

The steps I did:

- substring the date to take only the date
- convert it to int
- divide by 7
- [ceil](https://impala.apache.org/docs/build/html/topics/impala_math_functions.html#math_functions__ceil) the result